# Monomorphism Restriction, ghci, and let expression

Tags: haskell

This expression is incorrect.

```
f = show
```

However, in **ghci** this is legit

```
let f = show
```

Moreover, its type is changed to

```
() -> String
```

Is there any explanation of this phenomenon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **ghci** prompt behaves as if the [`ExtendedDefaultRules`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules) extension is enabled.

In particular this means that:

> The unit type () is added to the start of the standard list of types
>   which are tried when doing type defaulting.

So to get the same behaviour from a source file, either compile with `-XExtendedDefaultRules`, or add `{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}` to the top of the file.