# Why is "(2+2.0)" Double in a .hs file but "Fractional a => a" in GHCi?

Tags: haskell

Loading `a = 2+2.0` from a `.hs` file in GHCi and doing `:t a` shows `a :: Double`.

On the other hand, doing `let b = 2+2.0` and `:t b` in GHCi shows `b :: Fractional a => a`.

How are you able to deduce this from these two documents?

- 4.3.4 Ambiguous Types, and Defaults for Overloaded Numeric Operations https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-750004.3
- 2.4.8 Type defaulting in GHCi: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html

I find this official documentation almost incomprehensible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monomorphism Restriction, ghci, and let expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476975/monomorphism-restriction-ghci-and-let-expression)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-set.html#ghci-interactive-options) is what you want, I think.  Basically, GHC implements a different language by default in GHCi than in a module; in particular, the dreaded monomorphism restriction is enabled by default in a module (as per the language) whereas in GHCi it's disabled.  The monomorphism restriction is what causes GHC to pick a monomorphic type for your `a`, whereas, with it turned off, GHC is free to generalize the type of `b`, yielding the polymorphic type you see.

Answer (score 2):

The key is that GHCi isn't defaulting the type of `b`. It takes the constraints `2 :: Num a => a` and `2.0 :: Fractional a => a` and unifies them to give `2 + 2.0 :: Fractional a => a`. When it loads a module, the compiler forces every value to have a concrete type, so `Fractional a` is defaulted to `Double`.