# Why doesn't f=(+) need a type annotation?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I mean, for example,

```
f :: (Enum a) => a -> a --without this line, there would be an error
f = succ
```

It's because `succ` needs its parameter to be enumerable (`succ :: (Enum a) => a -> a`)

but for `(+)`

```
f = (+) --ok
```

Though `(+)`'s declaration is `(+) :: (Num a) => a –> a –> a`.

I mean, why don't I need to declare `f` as `f :: (Num a) => a –> a –> a`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because of defaulting.  `Num` is a 'defaultable' type class, meaning that if you leave it un-constrained, the compiler will make a few intelligent guesses as to which type you meant to use it as.  Try putting that definition in a module, then running

```
:t f
```

in `ghci`; it should tell you (IIRC) `f :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer`.  The compiler didn't know which `a` you wanted to use, so it guessed `Integer`; and since that worked, it went with that guess.

Why didn't it infer a polymorphic type for `f`?  Because of the dreaded[1] monomorphism restriction.  When the compiler sees

```
f = (+)
```

it thinks '`f` is a value', which means it needs a single (monomorphic) type.  Eta-expand the definition to

```
f x = (+) x
```

and you will get the polymorphic type

```
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

and similarly if you eta-expand your first definition

```
f x = succ x
```

you don't need a type signature any more.

[1] Actual name from the GHC documentation!

Comment: When exactly does this reduction happen? `f = (+)` in ghci is not restricted.

Comment: @Bergi - the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336108/why-is-22-0-double-in-a-hs-file-but-fractional-a-a-in-ghci/28336620#28336620

Answer (score 7):

> I mean, why don't I need to declare `f` as `(+) :: (Num a) => a –> a –> a`?

You do need to do that, if you declare the signature of `f` at all. But if you don't, the compiler will “guess” the signature itself – in this case this isn't all to remarkable since it can basically just copy&paste the signature of `(+)`. And that's precisely what it will do.

...or at least what it should do. It does, provided you have the `-XNoMonomorphism` flag on. Otherwise, well, the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) steps in because `f`'s definition is of the shape [*ConstantApplicativeForm = Value*](https://wiki.haskell.org/CAF); that makes the compiler dumb down the signature to the next best *non-polymorphic* type it can find, namely `Integer -> Integer -> Integer`. To prevent this, you should in fact supply the right signature by hand, for all top-level functions. That also prevents a lot of confusion, and many errors become way less confusing.

The monomorphism restriction is the reason

```
f = succ
```

won't work on its own: because it also has this CAF shape, the compiler does not try to infer the correct polymorphic type, but tries to find some concrete instantiation to make a monomorphic signature. But unlike `Num`, the `Enum` class does not offer a default instance.

Possible solutions, ordered by preference:

1. *Always add signatures.* You really should.
2. Enable `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`.
3. Write your function definitions in the form `f a = succ a`, `f a b = a+b`. Because there are explicitly mentioned arguments, these don't qualify as CAF, so the monomorphism restriction won't kick in.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell defaults `Num` constraints to `Int` or `Integer`, I forget which.